# Why .NET MVC isn't able to bind an AJAX uploaded file to HttpPostedFileBase?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, httppostedfilebase

I've been struggling with AJAX file uploading for a while in a .NET MVC 3 project and had found several problems during my research.

First of all, seems that there are quite a bunch of questions here at Stack Overflow stating that there's not possible to upload a file through AJAX. I think that all of these answers are from a time before XMLHttpRequest Level 2 specification, but maybe it'd be a good idea to update them now.

Respecting my current question, I'm trying to manage the upload into my controller, but I'm having quite a hard time, as I'm being unable to use HttpPostedFileBase to load the uploaded file (as I do on a normal form file upload).

My question is... why this happen? I mean... when you sen the file through AJAX the POST to the server include the same info as when you send it through the form, isn't it? 
And the file is still into Request.Files, then... why the controller cannot bind that info to a HttpPostedFileBase instance passed as a parameter to the controller?

EDIT: I add AJAX upload code example as suggested in comments:

```
$("#uploadButton").click(function () {
    if (window.FormData) {
        var theFile = $('input[type="file"]').get(0).files[0];
        var formData = new window.FormData();
        formData.append("importedFile", theFile);
        $.ajax({ async: false,
            url: $.url("Courses/Import/"),
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: "multipart/form-data",
            success: function (res) {
                $("#response").innerHTML = res;
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

On server side, the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase importedFile) {
    //Here importedFile is null, however Request.Files[0] contains the uploaded file.
}
```

Comment: It would help if you would show us your JavaScript. The typical issue in this case is that file has no name and binder can't find it in dictionary collection which is build internally from request - but that can't be confirmed without your code.